# Unknown column 'Amsterdam' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display certain data from tableA in the database, but only the ones which have similar location as the user from tableB, who is logged in.

I am using the code below, but I get the following error: Unknown column 'Amsterdam' in 'where clause'.

The code I am using is:

```
     $query = 'SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE `city` LIKE '.$user['city'].' ORDER BY `id` DESC';
     $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
     $row_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


     echo $row_result['name'];
```

What do you think might be the error?

Comment: Try this `LIKE "'.$user['city'].'"`

Comment: You're missing the quotes around the city. Don't concatenate data and sql, use prepared statements !

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated and unsafe! Use PDO or `mysqli_`, instead. I think there should be a big red banner saying this on all newspapers and books printed.

Comment: This is why prepared statements/bind variables are so useful.... you don't need to remember to wrap your string arguments in quotes

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the value of `$user['city']` with single quotation marks.
Assuming the city is Amsterdam, what you are aiming for is a SQL statement that reads:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE `city` LIKE 'Amsterdam' ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

but what you are generating is:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE `city` LIKE Amsterdam ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

so MySQL is treating the name of the city as a table column, because it is not enclosed.
Your code needs to be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE `city` LIKE '".$user['city']."' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row_result['name'];
```

The above example used double-quotes to enclose the static text, but you can use single-quotes by escaping the ones that need to form the string value:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE `city` LIKE \''.$user['city'].'\' ORDER BY `id` DESC';
```

Answer (score 1):

`city` is a text field. Therefore the SQL parser expects text, which has to be in quotes.

"'.$user['city'].'"

Answer (score 1):

You may want to put additional quotes around $user['city'] as below:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE `city` LIKE `'.$user['city'].'` ORDER BY `id` DESC';
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you're missing the quote marks around `$user['city']`

Aside from that, can I recommend that you stop using the `mysql_` functions as they've been deprecated.

If you move to `mysqli_` or `PDO::` calls, you open up the possibility of using prepared statements which will make life a lot easier and may actually give you cause to think "How did I ever cope without these?"